# setting two states with onClick

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to disable one of the button, when clicked but it is not working. onClick is changing two states, one for the text and one to disable the button.

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState();
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
 
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Data is {loading ? "Loading" : "not Loading"} </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setLoading(true);
          setDisable(true);
        }}
        disabled={disable}
      >
        ON
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setLoading(false);
          setDisable(false);
        }}
        disabled={disable}
      >
        OFF
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do instead?

Comment: You have to add the default value for your loading useState like the disable useState. const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); however, you can use the same state to do both things.

Comment: @msmoore trying to disable one of the button based on the text "loading" or "not loading".

Comment: @Eriksen giving no default value means it is falsy, so that does not help , however can you show me how to use the same state to do both things?

Comment: @MHassankhan just use one of them. You have two states that have the same value always. You can use loading for your paragraph and for your disabled property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set the "OFF" button to `disabled={!disable}`

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setDisable(false);
    }}
    disabled={!disable}
  >
    OFF
  </button>
```